# Keycloak Adapter Integration Test fails error Must set 'realm' in config

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, realm, keycloak

I am using keycloak 4.4.0 Final, below is project structure
[image]

Parent A pom Contains all the dependencyManagement below is the psedocode

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-spi</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-model-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-servlet-filter-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-spi</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-legacy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-wildfly-adapter-dist</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and in Child B i am adding the dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-spi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Integration test in Sub Child D is getting failed, giving exception" java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config ". surprising is if i add keycloak-legacy-spring-boot-starter dependency to Child B pom test are passed with out exception. No change in test code.

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "Development")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = FacebookTestConfiguration.class)
public class FacebookGreetingClientShouldTest {   
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    FacebookGreetingClient greetingClient;

    FacebookChannelConfiguration facebookChannelConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    MockFacebookServer facebookServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        facebookChannelConfiguration = new FacebookChannelConfiguration();
        Deencapsulation.setField(facebookChannelConfiguration, "url", "/facebookTest");
        Deencapsulation.setField(facebookChannelConfiguration, "valid", true);
        FacebookToken fbAccessToken = new FacebookToken();
        fbAccessToken.setSecureValue("abcdfghf");
        facebookChannelConfiguration.setAccessToken(fbAccessToken);
        facebookChannelConfiguration.setGreeting("greeting");
        Deencapsulation.setField(facebookChannelConfiguration, "fbClient",
                testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate());
    }
    @After
    public void destroy() {
        facebookServer.data.clear();
    } 
    @Test
    public void greetingsTest() throws Exception { 
        try {
            greetingClient = new FacebookGreetingClient(facebookChannelConfiguration);
            greetingClient.run();
            Assert.assertEquals(2, facebookServer.data.size());             Assert.assertTrue(facebookServer.data.get(0).toString().contains("get_started"));             Assert.assertTrue(facebookServer.data.get(1).toString().contains("greeting"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
}
```

> NOTE: strange behaviour is if i remove keycloak-legacy-spring-boot-starter dependencies from Parent A pom dependencyManagement and added it to Child B pom dependencyManagement, test are passed, no error or exception. No change in test code
>   Can any one help me.

Exception :java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config when keycloak-legacy-spring-boot-starter dependencies added to Child B

Comment: Are you setting the realm in a properties file? For the dependency management question I'd suggest doing a `mvn clean install -DskipTests` again at the top level and seeing if it still happens and then a `mvn depdency:tree` at the level of each module to see if they get the same versions of the adapter. But I'd suggest the more important thing is whether a realm is configured for the space of that integration test, assuming you do mean to be using keycloak for that test.

Comment: yeah in application.properties i am setting keycloak.auth-server-url, keycloak.realm, keycloak.resource.

Comment: So presumably it is loading that config in one case and not the other. You can try running in debug mode and breakpointing KeycloakSpringBootProperties.class. Also try KeycloakAutoConfiguration.class and also the TestRestTemplate. This might help show what the difference is between the two cases.